# search in txt file and put the result in text box

Tags: c#, file

i have a text file like that :

```
; "one"
id_number:*=344E6F4D6F7265486178785454332100

; "two"

id_number:*=3536336A775E3825246E773543563437

; "three"

id:_number*=BDBD2EB72D82473DBE09F1B552A8983
```

and lots the same way and what i want to search in the file for the the title (two) and after that it's give me the id_number of it and i want to put the id_number in `textbox`

i used

```
string[] s = File.ReadAllLines("MyFilePath.txt");
List<byte[]> byteArrays = new List<byte[]>();
foreach (string st in s.Where(x => x.Trim().StartsWith("id_number:*=")).Select(x => x.Skip(12)))
{
    byte[] b = new byte[(int)((st.Length + 1) / 2)];
    for (int i = 0; i < (int)((st.Length + 1) / 2); i++)
    {
        var byteString = (st.Skip(2 * i).length > 2) ? st.Skip(2 * i).Take(2) : "0" + st.Skip(2 * i);
        var bt = Convert.ToByte(byteString, 16);
        b[i] = bt;
    }
    byteArrays.Add(b);
```

but it doesn't work

Comment: @Rhumborl i edit and put the code but dosen't work

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
string s, result;
bool bl = false;

using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader("....txt"))
{
    while ((s = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
    {
        if(s.Contains ("two"))
        {
            bl = true;
        }

        if (s.Contains("id_number") && bl == true)
        {
            result = s.Replace("id_number:*=", "");

            textBox1.Text = result;

            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    const string f = @"C:\test.txt";

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        // 1
        // Declare new List.
        List<string> lines = new List<string>();

        // 2
        // Use using StreamReader for disposing.
        using (StreamReader r = new StreamReader(f))
        {
            // 3
            // Use while != null pattern for loop
            string line;
            while ((line = r.ReadLine()) != null)
            {

                // 4
                // Insert logic here.
                // ...
                // "line" is a line in the file. Add it to our List.

                if (line.Trim() == "")
                    continue;

                lines.Add(line);
            }
        }

        // 5

        string stringValue = "two";
        int correctIndex = -1;
        // Print out all the lines.
        for (int i=0; i<lines.Count; i++)
        {
            if (lines[i].Contains(stringValue))
            {
                correctIndex = i;
            }
        }

        if(correctIndex == -1)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("item is not found");
        }
        else
        {
            //here you will need probably little more cleaning of the string. If the strings are on 1 line you should search for lines[correctIndex]
            Console.WriteLine(lines[correctIndex + 1]);
        }
    }
}
```

EDIT: I don't see your edit, check if my solution helps you. Write me a comment if you want to continue with your solution.

Here this should work. Hope this helps you.

Comment: @user3227682 doesnt matter if you dont use the console, you can put the code inside `Main` anywhere

Comment: @user3227682 probably your fileName is not test, but you can change it. Copy the code and use it anywhere. Rhumborl already point that.

Comment: there are error on     using (StreamReader r = new StreamReader(f)) in f  @mybirthname

Comment: @user3227682 probably because you write wrong path for your files. Also this is working without an error, next time read the exception and try to fix it.

Comment: thank you every thing work well but i want the third line @mybirthname

Comment: @user3227682 change value of stringValue from Texbox to what you want to find. Also if my answer helped you accept it !